# List attachments in report field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with attached files to each record, and I would like to get all the filenames listed according their records when I run a report.
For the moment, my query only displays the last filename.
Any advice?

Comment: Can you please add your existing query by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub report based on attachment field of the record. The query of the sub report should be something like this:

`SELECT Record_Id, Attachment_field_name.FileName from TableName`

Link your sub report on the Record_id with the main report. Substitute with your field names.

Also have look at this related question on attachment fields [How to query number of attachments from Attachment field in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194224/how-to-query-number-of-attachments-from-attachment-field-in-microsoft-access)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I get the following error message when running the query: "unable to execute query. Invalid operation or syntax using multi-value field".
`SELECT [Record Id], AttachmentName("Table3", "AttachedFile", "[Record Id] = " & Forms![Form1]![Record ref]) AS [Attachment Name]
FROM [Table3]
WHERE [Code ref] = Forms![Form1]![Code];`

Comment: Based on your info try: `SELECT [Record Id], [AttachedFile].[FileName] FROM Table3 WHERE [Record id] = Forms![Form1]![Record ref]`